# Response is not getting in codeigniter ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, response

My controller function is like this

```
function check_user() {
        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $res_user = $this->user_model->is_unique_user($user_name);
}
```

And I have user ajax code like below

```
success: function(response){
                                if(response.data == 'exist'){
                                    $("#user_name").after('<p class="help-block">Username alredy exist</p>');
                                }
                                                                    else{
                                                                            $("#user_name").after('<p class="help-block">Username available</p>');
                                }
```

And here is my model function for this

```
function is_unique_user($user_name)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where("user_name = '$user_name'");
    $result = $this->db->get('tb_user');

    if($result->num_rows())
    {
        return $date = 'exist';
    }
    else
    {
        return $data = 'available';
    }
}
```

Now the issue is query is working fine. But No error message. I checked using fire-bug console. It shows error that there is no response. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use `die` to stop code and return response.

```
function check_user() {
        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
       $res_user = $this->user_model->is_unique_user($user_name);
       die($res_user);
}
```

And ajax sucess function change `response.data` to `response`

```
success: function(response){
        if(response == 'exist'){
             $("#user_name").after('<p class="help-block">Username alredy exist</p>');
         }else{
             $("#user_name").after('<p class="help-block">Username available</p>');
       }
```

Comment: It is shows "available". Can you please check that ajax part? I am little confused there

Comment: @joelcj, i have updated answer, the issue in ajax success function, please change `response.data` to `response` because ajax response in html.

Comment: Again another problem. I am getting response. But I need to show this in page. That if condition not working. In console I can see response as required. But not error message in page

Answer (score 1):

please review this code ,use `echo` to get response

```
function check_user() {
        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
       echo   $res_user = $this->user_model->is_unique_user($user_name);
}
```

Comment: Tried that dude. It prints "available"

Comment: I think the issue is with taking response in ajax code. Please check there